# trying to set image size but getting error on setState

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to upload two images and after they are uploaded, I am cropping the images and storing the cropped result in cropResult state. I am also trying to get the image's height and width and for this purpose I have tried to use a more simple logic but while setting state for height and width I am getting the following error

```
',' expected.
```

at the starting square bracket of

> imgObject[img.name

below is my code

```
this.state = {
  fileName: [],
  src:'',
  img1Size: {},
  img2Size: {},
  cropResult: null,
  cropResult1: null,
  showCroppedImage: false,
  showCroppedImage1: false,
}
```

```
    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
      

        let files;
        if (e.dataTransfer) {
          files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        } else if (e.target) {
            let today = new Date().getTime() / 1000+e.target.files[0].name;

            this.state.fileName.push(today)
            files = e.target.files;
        }
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
          this.setState({ src: reader.result });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      }
```

```
  onImgLoad({target:img}) {
        let imgObject = {
            'cropResult': img1Size,
            'cropResult1': img2Size
        }
        
       this.setState({imgObject[img.name]: {height:img.offsetHeight, width:img.offsetWidth}}   
    }
```

```
 { this.state.showCroppedImage ? 
     <div className = "mr-3">
        <div className="box cropperRemove mt-2" >
          <img className="noImage" src={this.state.cropResult} name="cropResult" onLoad={(e) => this.onImgLoad(e)} />
         </div>
     </div> :  
     <><input type="file" data-id="main" name = "mainImg" ref={input => this.inputElement = input} onChange={this.onChange} className="noDisplay" required/>
    
<img src={noImage} alt="noImage" onClick={() => this.inputElement.click()} className="noImage" /></>
}

{ this.state.showCroppedImage1 ? 
    <div className = "mr-3">
      <div className="box cropperRemove mt-2" >
        <img className="noImage" src={this.state.cropResult1} onLoad={this.onImgLoad} name="cropResult1" />
        </div>
    </div> :  
     <><input type="file" data-id="second" name = "secImg" ref={input => this.inputElement1 = input} onChange={this.onChange} className="noDisplay" />

<img src={noImage} alt="noImage" onClick={() => this.inputElement1.click()} className="noImage" /> </>
 }
```

Is it possible to optimise the above code? I have been thinking about it but couldn't come up with a solution as the "this.state.showCroppedImage1" is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your object literal, not with setState.
Do it like this :

```
this.setState({[imgObject[img.name]]: {height:img.offsetHeight, width:img.offsetWidth}})
```

The only change is to replace `imgObject[img.name]` with `[imgObject[img.name]]`.

This is how you can use dynamic property name in object literal.